# get hour from TTime object without using DecodeTime method

Tags: datetime, c++builder

Is it possible to retrieve hour from TTime object in c++ builder

without using DecodeTime(args), by doing calculations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HourOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.HourOf) function returns the current hour of a TDateTime value.

```cpp
// get hour from the current time
int Hour;
Hour = HourOf(Now());
```

Have a look at the [DateUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils) unit, which include lots of useful functions for handing dates and times.

Comment: Thanks man! Before that I always used DecodeTime(*args) method, and now I find it the best choice one!